# check if the function works inside another function

Tags: python

I have the following functions:

```
def outer_function():
    return 'It worked'

def fun():
    try:
        return function1()
    except:
        return function2()
```

When executing `fun()`I would like to check that if `function1()` works correctly, then `fun()` can return an array such as this

```
[function1(),outer_function()]
```

How could I check whether `function1()` works inside ´`fun()` and return an output such as the desired one?

Comment: Instead of `return function1()`, do `return [function1(), outer_function()]`

Comment: But what if `function1()` didn't worked? It would return the array anyway..

Comment: No you wouldn't because `function1()` would `raise` and it would hit the `except` case before being able to return that list

Comment: What error could function1() throw?

Comment: @coldspeed It depends, but that wouldn't really be important to the question. All that matters is that it could raise an exception.

Comment: @Victor No it is important. You don't want to confuse an error thrown by function2() with that thrown by function1(), assuming both can throw errors, and you wouldn't know what's failing unless you print out the traceback.

Comment: I know we push for *Minimal* Complete Verifiable Examples, but if anything this example is *too* minimal. We have no way of knowing what `function1`, `function2`, `fun`, or `outer_function` is really doing, so it's hard to advise on what would be best. This sounds like a bad idea, honestly, but it's hard to tell without a more concrete definition.

Comment: @CoryKramer I'm not sure that the python language specifications imply that in `[f(), g()]`, function f is executed before g. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @Gribouillis They are [specified to evaluate left to right](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order)

Comment: @CoryKramer but `[f(), g()]` is not on the list, so the proof is not sufficient. It is not only a comma separated expression surrounded by square brackets, it is a literal list constructor. Although obviously I don't think any existing implementation evaluates in reverse order.

Comment: @coldspeed I guess I'm making the assumption that `outer_function` and `function2` both work, since the OP only mentioned that he was worried whether `function1` worked or not. But yes, my response is contingent on the fact that `function2` and `outer_function` are functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of return `function1()`, do `return [function1(), outer_function()]`

So your function would be:

```
def fun():
    try:
        return [function1(), outer_function()]
    except:
        return function2()
```

If `function1()` raises an error, the array will NOT be returned. Instead, the try block will catch the Exception.

NOTE: This code is contingent on the fact that `function2` and `outer_function` will not raise any errors of their own.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a variable for function1 output, and if function1 throws an error it will stop the return statement and go into the catch/except. Otherwise it will go to the else statement and return the desired array:

```
def outer_function():
return 'It worked'

def fun():
    try:
        x = function1()
    except:
        return function2()
    else:
        return [x, outer_function()]
```

Comment: This works, but it is unnecessary :) You can bypass the separate variable

Comment: True. I just thought it would be easier to understand. I'll edit

Comment: I would `x = function1()` in the try, then add an `else: return [x, outer_function()]` after the except part. This allows exception that occur in `outer_function()` to propagate.

Comment: @Gribouillis why would there be an exception in there, all it does is return

Comment: I think it's only an example, `outer_function()` may become thicker.

Comment: Ok that's fair. I will change it

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your question and made it on 'Repl.it' Online Compiler.
[Here Your Link](https://repl.it/J7aF/3)

```
def function1():
  try:
    return True
  except :
    return False

def function2():
  try:
    return True
  except:
    return False

def outer_function():
  return 'It worked'

def fun():
  if function1():
    return [function1(), outer_function()]
  else:
    return function2()

print(fun())
```